# How do I build a SQL query to show two columns of different date ranges?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I'm trying to build a query from an Oracle 11g database to use in a report. I need to use two tables CONTACT and CONTACT_EXT to get the data from, and compare the total amount of contacts over two date ranges.The tables are joined by ID's matching.

CONTACT:

```
ID | DATE
----------
1   12/12/2010
2   12/11/2010
3   14/09/2011
```

CONTACT_EXT

```
 ID | TYPE
----------
1   MAIL
2   FAX
3   FAX
```

So for example if I set period A to be between 01/01/2010 and 12/12/2010 and period B to be between 01/01/2011 and 11/11/2011

```
TYPE | PERIOD A | PERIOD B | TOTAL
MAIL   1          0          1
FAX    1          1          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a self join:

```
select type,period_a,period_b,period_a+period_b as total
from(
  select type,count(1) as period_a
  from contact_ext
  left join contact
  using(id)
  where date>='20100101' and date<='20101212'
  group by 1
)a
join(
  select type,count(1) as period_b
  from contact_ext
  left join contact
  using(id)
  where date>='20110101' and date<='20111111'
  group by 1
)b
using(type);
```

Comment: I've tested this and it worked exactly how I wanted, thanks so much!

Comment: I'd like to point out that this query does more work than needed, because it has to visit each table twice.

Answer (score 3):

```
SQL> create table contact (id,cdate)
  2  as
  3  select 1, date '2010-12-12' from dual union all
  4  select 2, date '2010-11-12' from dual union all
  5  select 3, date '2011-09-14' from dual
  6  /

Table created.

SQL> create table contact_ext (id,type)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'MAIL' from dual union all
  4  select 2, 'FAX' from dual union all
  5  select 3, 'FAX' from dual
  6  /

Table created.

SQL> select ce.type
  2       , count(case when c.cdate between date '2010-01-01' and date '2010-12-12' then 1 end) period_a
  3       , count(case when c.cdate between date '2011-01-01' and date '2011-11-11' then 1 end) period_b
  4       , count(*) total
  5    from contact c
  6         inner join contact_ext ce on (c.id = ce.id)
  7   group by ce.type
  8  /

TYPE   PERIOD_A   PERIOD_B      TOTAL
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
FAX           1          1          2
MAIL          1          0          1

2 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, as the accepted answer does not handle the case where we have a value in Period B but not in Period A (ie the row isn't returned)

One issue with this is that the totals are wrong as the values are 'double counted' on overlapping values.

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1 : In where clause set period A between 01/01/2010 and 12/12/2010 OR period B between 01/01/2011 and 11/11/2011 
In where clause use OR condition

Ans 2: you can union two different select statements of Period A and Period B